# True average CPU usage

Tags: linux, htop, cpu-usage

On my system with 32 physical cores I'm constantly spawning 100 threads that run for anywhere between 0 and 3 seconds. After all are finished, the next batch is spawned.

I'd like to get correct average cpu usage, i.e. to what percentage are these cores used on a say 1 minute average. If they are idle for 30% of the time, that value should be 0.7

When using htop, I get a load average of more than 40 which higher than the number of cores However, as can be seen in [this video](https://youtu.be/wRDYH1SP9uI), the CPU cores are not always used to 100%. This is what I expect as all 100 threads have to finish before new ones are generated.

How can I get a more precise measurement of CPU usage?

Comment: Does your system support hyperthreading?  If so, you might be running two threads on each core.

Comment: Nope, it's definitely disabled / not even supported.

Comment: What kind of average? I suspect you want _mean_, but it could also be _median_ (or possibly even _mode_).

Comment: It's the mean I want.

Answer (score 1):

Load average is not the cpu usage per say. This is an often cited [explanation of what Load Average means](http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2009/07/31/understanding-load-averages). So a load average of 40 seems pretty reasonable for 100 threads that don't quite use 100% of a core.

To measure the actual CPU usage, I would look into using [perf](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial) which can read hardware performance counters. Perf is a pretty powerful tool and can measure many things, in your case I might try:

```
perf stat -e cycles ./your_executable
```